# How to use the connected wallet in getNftsForOwner for Alchemy SDK function?

Tags: react, typescript, wagmi, nextjs, alchemy-sdk

I'm using a combination of Thirdweb and Alchemy SDK to fetch all nfts in a connected wallet. Every example I've come across for Alchemy's getNftsForOwner function has the wallet address placed in the function like so:

```
const NFTs = await alchemy.nft.getNftsForOwner("0x0000");
```

I'm trying to figure out how to use the connected wallet in the function. I use Thirdweb's connect wallet and useAddress hook to get the address but I don't have to go that route if there is a better way to make it work.

My current setup is:

```
const router = useRouter();
const { walletAddress } = router.query;
const [NFTs, setNFTs] = useState<OwnedNftsResponse>()
const address = useAddress();
  
 


 useEffect( () => {
    async function grabber() {
        const NFTs = await alchemy.nft.getNftsForOwner(???);
      setNFTs(NFTs);
    }
    grabber();
  }, [NFTs]);
```

Every attempt I've tried to use the connected wallet address resulted in Error: 400: owner is a required request parameter

Answer (score 0):

You need the wallet address to pass to the getNftsForOwner() function like so

const NFTs = getNftsForOwner(0xblahblahblahblah123blah)